# How do I use cookie for Locale and redirect according to Locale in LocaleEventListener in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-2.1

I want to do override LocaleEventListener in Symfony 3 with the following scenario:

Scenario 1: 
I need to set Locale in Cookie say for example `en|de`

Scenario 2: 
Need to get `requestUri = "/"` and check if we have Locale in the cookie

Scenario 3:
If we have Locale in the previous page ( e.g.: `domain.com/en` ) 
and 
now in the root domain ( e.g. `domain.com` )

then ==> redirect to `domain.com/en`

Result: So that user system can detect the previous language in the cookie and redirect to the user if hit on root domain

Purpose: 
Most users switch the language but sometimes they are opening a new tab with the main domain ( where we have default language ) - but users want their previous language.

How do I overcome this issue by fulfilling the purpose?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why you don't use it on routes {_locale} ?

Comment: @Albeis I am using `{_locale}` in route but for the root domain, I can not keep user with previous language .